# Were 3-manifolds with $\sec>0$ known to be space forms before Ricci flow?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, 3-manifolds

It is well known that R. Hamilton ([JDG 1982](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214436922)) used Ricci flow to show that a closed $3$-manifold with *positive Ricci curvature* must be diffeomorphic to a spherical space form $S^3/\Gamma$, since such metrics evolve to a limit which has constant curvature.

Together with some colleagues, I was under the suspicion that it was previously known that closed $3$-manifolds with *positive sectional curvature* satisfied this conclusion, but cannot seem to find such an earlier proof independent of Ricci flow. More precisely, I suspected it was possible to prove this statement by establishing that the Heegaard genus of such a manifold must be $\leq2$. So here is my:

> **Question.** Is there a proof that if a closed manifold $M^3$ has $\sec>0$ then $M^3\cong S^3/\Gamma$ using Heegaard splittings instead of Ricci flow?

Comment: Is there an analogous result for 2 manifolds which is done without Ricci flow?

Comment: For 2-manifolds you can simply use the uniformization theorem, which longly predates any Ricci flow techniques.

Comment: It was known (after Hamilton's theorem) by Thurston's orbifold theorem) that genus 2 manifolds satisfy geometrization (one can now prove this independent of Rocci flow). But I don't know how to prove these manifolds are genus 2.

Comment: In dim 3, obviously they are homology 3-sphere. then you need prove that positive sec/Ricci implies being sphere in simply connected case that is same as RH theorem.

Answer (score 12):

No, this was not known before Hamilton's paper. I think a Ricci-flow-free argument would still be of interest, so if you know how to do it, by all means...